# Change Jupyter Notebook's localhost:8888 default server with other

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-console

i have two machines connected via lan.
other system's ip address is 192.1xx.x.x
i want to run jupyter ipython query's on my machine which can be exexuted on his machine.
at the start of ipython notebook, there is a black screen which contains this:

```
[I 11:12:52.802 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
```

can i change this to my specified location?

Answer (score 13):

You can specify the port you want Jupyter to run uncommenting/editing the following line in `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`:

```
#c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

In case you don't have a `jupyter_notebook_config.py` try running `jupyter notebook --generate-config`. See [this](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) for further details on Jupyter configuration.

In case you are accessing Jupyter at a remote machine you can also try just leaving Jupyter running at its default port and make an SSH tunnel to your local machine at the port you want, e.g.:

```
ssh -fNL <new port>:localhost:8888 <your ssh config>
```

Answer (score 9):

Run the Anaconda Prompt, generate the config file, if you don't have it and edit the config file and change c.NotebookApp.ip with your IP Adress '192.1xx.x.x'

On Anaconda Prompt:
If the file not exist, generate a config file:

```
    jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Output:

```
    (base) C:\Users\youruser>jupyter notebook --generate-config
    Writing default config to: C:\Users\youruser\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py
    (base) C:\Users\youruser>
```

Change to jupyter directory:

```
    cd .jupyter
```

Modify the config file from:

```
    ## The IP address the notebook server will listen on.
    #c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'
```

To:

```
    ## The IP address the notebook server will listen on.
    c.NotebookApp.ip = '192.1xx.x.x'
```

Answer (score 7):

First you need to generate a configuration file by typing:

```
$> jupyter notebook --generate-config
Writing default config to: /{home-directory}/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Next you need to edit that configuration to change the port number:

```
vi /{home-directory}/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Look for the following line (which is commented out by default) and comment in the line and change the port number:

```
(default configuration)
## The port the notebook server will listen on.
# c.NotebookApp.port = 8888

(comment removed, port changed)
## The port the notebook server will listen on.
c.NotebookApp.port = 9999
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, I had to use my machine's name instead of `localhost`.

To get this, open a terminal and run:

```
hostname
```

So in the browser, instead of `localhost:8888/...` I entered `mac-mini.home:8888/...` (where ... represents the rest of the url).

I'd like to find out where in the Jupyter config this can be overridden, because it is not intuitive, IMO.