# Unable to open jupyter notebook : port 8889 already in use

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have tried to open the jupyter notebook via anaconda and jupyter terminal. But getting the error message that "port already in use" . I have reinstalled anaconda many timing but isn't worked for me.

And getting this message "This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500" on the screen.

I am using python 2.7

Comment: Uhm....have you tried to see what process is using the 8889 port and maybe kill it?

Comment: See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373330/change-jupyter-notebooks-localhost8888-default-server-with-other/40436673). This isn't a problem with jupyter. There's just another program that's already using that port. Or Jupyter is already running, and you just don't know it.

Comment: @Adi I am not getting anything application which is using all these ports.

Comment: @David Culbreth, thanks for help. But getting same issue even after changing the port no. in config. file.

Comment: Check these logs: may be helpful to get the issue:

Answer (score 3):

Port 8889 is used by another Jupyter session. You can just kill the task that's using it, or you can run

```
jupyter notebook list
```

to check current notebooks. you can run

```
jupyter notebook --port 8888
```

you can also use another port instead of 8888,just replace 8888 by any other number you'd like.

Comment: I am getting nothing in server list (jupyter notebook list). and also tried by changing all the port, still getting this message "This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500" on the screen.